# How do I stop a pyspark dataframe from changing to a list?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I start with a pyspark dataframe and gets converted to a list after I use .take() on it.  How can I keep it a pyspark dataframe?

```
    df1 = Ce_clean
    print(type(df1))
    df1 = df1.take(1000)
    print(type(df1))
```

<class 'pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame'>

<class 'list'>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either convert the `RDD/list` to df **or** use `limit(n)`

```py
 df2 = spark.createDataFrame(df1.take(100))
 type(df2)
 <class 'pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame'>
```

or

```
 df3 = df1.limit(100)
 type(df3)
 <class 'pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame'>
```